# Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'if' can I add if statement?

Tags: asp.net

Excuse me,
I am following [This Tutorial](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource12-How-to-implement-paging-and-sorting-in-aspnet-Gridview-control.aspx)
a part of code need to be fixed in my app.
I modify this code:

```
<%=GridVwPagingSorting.PageCount%>
```

To like this:

```
 <%= if(GridViewPaging.PageCount == 0) { GridViewPaging.PageCount + 1 }else{GridViewPaging.PageCount}  %>
```

But I am getting error:

```
Line 44:             <%= if(GridViewPaging.PageCount == 0) { GridViewPaging.PageCount + 1 }else{GridViewPaging.PageCount}  %>
```

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term 'if'

what pogramming language is it?
beginning with
<%=
and end with 
%>
can I add if statement?

Comment: The language is C#.  `<%=` and `%>` are for inline code, though I'm not sure why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's c# in asp.net. 
What about ternary operator? Like:

```
<%=(GridViewPaging.PageCount==0)?GridViewPaging.PageCount + 1:GridViewPaging.PageCount %>
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'  Line 44:            <%= GridViewPaging.PageCount?GridViewPaging.PageCount + 1:GridViewPaging.PageCount %>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add if statement on aspx page. The error `Invalid expression term 'if'` is due to '=' with '<%='. You can use condition as `"<% if(GridViewPaging.PageCount == 0){} %>"`.